# Input value isn't getting carried forward when form is submitted

Tags: javascript

I am feeling really guilty for asking this question. However, I tried everything and nothing worked...forcing me to ask here. If suggested, I will delete this question.

On chrome console of website: https://search.cisco.com/search?tab=Cisco&locale=enUS,
I performed following:

1. `document.getElementById("searchT").value = "Hello World!"` `//works fine`
2. `document.getElementById("searchform").submit() ;`

Line 1 works fine and fills the input with `"Hello World!"`. Line 2 submits the form and page reloads but somehow the `"Hello World!"` isnt getting carried forward when the page loads. It would be great if someone could explain why is it happening?

Comment: Without knowing more info about what frameworks you are using - that is the default way it is supposed to work. If the page has reloaded, all the form fields will be set back to their default values. Some frameworks do what you are expecting though, for instance: ASP.Net's older WebForm model using viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

You are populating value to the input field and then submitting the form.
Form action is equal to dot so its realoding the page.
The input field you set value does not have any `name` atrtibute so its missing in the query field in the url address and it looks like nothing were submitted.

When you type search term from keyboard other scripts perform (maybe ajax) requests and present you the results without page reload.

**EDITED**
When you hit enter on the keyboard scripts are reloading the page with ?query=searc-term parameter. And query is not the name of the text input you are populating the value

Answer (score 0):

Step one put `Hello World!` in the search field. Step two submitted the search form. It should have brought back the search results for `Hello World!`, but it didn't.

What happened?

**I took a look at the code for the form** and this is what I saw:

[image: cisco form code]

It has normal html form properties like `id`, `class` and `action`.

**It also has an extra property on it: `ng-submit`**.

A quick google search for `ng-submit` led me to discover this:

> ngSubmit
>
> - directive in module ng
>
> Enables binding angular expressions to onsubmit events.
>
> **Additionally it prevents the default action (which for form means sending the request to the server and reloading the current page)**, but only if the form does not contain action, data-action, or x-action attributes.
>
> source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

From this, we can determine two things:

1. Cisco using Angular's `ng-submit` to collect the query and return the search results.
2. The search feature was not designed to work without Angular's `ng-submit`.

**You did everything correctly; unfortunately the search feature isn't designed to work by normally submitting a form; it needs to be Angular's `ng-submit`**.